# I was called this recently by a friend but I can't remember what it was

Tags: terminology

I'm homeless and live in a tent so I'm constantly having to fix things instead of throwing them away or replacing it all together so I come up with ways to solve my problem with what I have on hand. 
Ingenuity is similar to the word I'm looking for by definition.

Comment: Nothing to do with linguistics

Comment: @Wilson Indeed. We should migrate to ELU

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same, but [tinker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tinker), perhaps?